# How to store list of Pandas data frame for easy access

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of data frame,

```
df1 = 
    Stock  Year   Profit  CountPercent
     AAPL  2012    1       38.77
     AAPL  2013    1       33.33
df2 = 
    Stock  Year   Profit  CountPercent
    GOOG   2012    1       43.47
    GOOG   2013    1       32.35

df3 = 
    Stock  Year   Profit  CountPercent
    ABC   2012    1       40.00
    ABC   2013    1       32.35
```

The out put of a function is [`df1,df2,df3,......`] like that, 
all the columns in the data frame will be same but the rows will be different,

how i can store these in hard disk and retrieve as a list again in most fast and efficient way?

Comment: are all your DFs have the same shape (# of rows and columns)?

Answer (score 1):

If values in columns `Stock` are same, you can remove this column by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) and use `dict comprehension` (key is first value of column `Stock` in each `df`):

```
dfs = {df.ix[0,'Stock']: df.iloc[:, 1:] for df in [df1,df2,df3]}

print (dfs['AAPL'])
   Year  Profit  CountPercent
0  2012       1         38.77
1  2013       1         33.33

print (dfs['ABC'])
   Year  Profit  CountPercent
0  2012       1         40.00
1  2013       1         32.35

print (dfs['GOOG'])
   Year  Profit  CountPercent
0  2012       1         43.47
1  2013       1         32.35
```

For storing in `disk` I think the best is use [hdf5 pytables](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables).

If values in each `Stack` column are same, you can [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) all `df` and then store it:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.set_index('Stock'), df2.set_index('Stock'), df3.set_index('Stock')])
print (df)
       Year  Profit  CountPercent
Stock                            
AAPL   2012       1         38.77
AAPL   2013       1         33.33
GOOG   2012       1         43.47
GOOG   2013       1         32.35
ABC    2012       1         40.00
ABC    2013       1         32.35

store = pd.HDFStore('store.h5')
store['df'] = df
print (store)
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: store.h5
/df            frame        (shape->[1,4])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if all your DFs have the same shape, then it would be more natural to store your data as `pandas.Panel` instead of list of DFs - this is how [pandas_datareader](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html) is working

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Stock,Year,Profit,CountPercent
AAPL,2012,1,38.77
AAPL,2013,1,33.33
"""
))

df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Stock,Year,Profit,CountPercent
GOOG,2012,1,43.47
GOOG,2013,1,32.35
"""
))

df3 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Stock,Year,Profit,CountPercent
ABC,2012,1,40.0
ABC,2013,1,32.35
"""
))


store = pd.HDFStore('c:/temp/stocks.h5')

# i had to drop `Stock` column and make it Panel-Axis, because of ERROR:
# TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [%s] because its data contents are [mixed-integer] object dtype
# when saving Panel to HDFStore ... 
p = pd.Panel({df.iat[0, 0]:df.drop('Stock', 1) for df in [df1,df2,df3]})

store = pd.HDFStore('c:/temp/stocks.h5')
store.append('stocks', p, data_columns=True, mode='w')
store.close()

# read panel from HDFStore
store = pd.HDFStore('c:/temp/stocks.h5')
p = store.select('stocks')
```

Store:

```
In [18]: store
Out[18]:
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: c:/temp/stocks.h5
/stocks            wide_table   (typ->appendable,nrows->6,ncols->3,indexers->[major_axis,minor_axis],dc->[AAPL,ABC,GOOG])
```

Panel dimensions:

```
In [19]: p['AAPL']
Out[19]:
     Year  Profit  CountPercent
0  2012.0     1.0         38.77
1  2013.0     1.0         33.33

In [20]: p[:, :, 'Profit']
Out[20]:
   AAPL  ABC  GOOG
0   1.0  1.0   1.0
1   1.0  1.0   1.0

In [21]: p[:, 0]
Out[21]:
                 AAPL     ABC     GOOG
Year          2012.00  2012.0  2012.00
Profit           1.00     1.0     1.00
CountPercent    38.77    40.0    43.47
```